# Problen running python scripts outside of Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

All my python scripts work just fine when I run them in Eclipse, however when I drage them over to the python.exe, they never work, the cmd opens and closes immediately. If I try to do it with a command in cmd, so it doesn't close, I get errors like:

**ImportErrror: No module named *Some Name***

and the likes.
How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: It might be that your module is not on python path. Just cd to your project root directory. Othervise third party modules are not on python path. What kind of module is missing?

Comment: It's a custom made file used by us, it's right next to the script Im trying to run, they're in the same directory.

Comment: could you also add commad line you're running? Like `cd <path to project>; python my_script.py`.

If you're trying to run it like `python <path to project>/my_script.py` python will not find extra file in project directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pathing is wrong. In eclipse right click on the project properties > PyDev - PYTHONPATH or Project References. The source folders show all of the pathing that eclipse automatically handles. It is likely that the module you are trying to import is in the parent directory.

```
Project
    src/
        my_module.py

    import_module.py
```

You may want to make a python package/library.

```
Project

    bin/
        my_module.py

    lib_name/
        __init__.py
        import_module.py
        other_module.py
```

In this instance my_module.py has no clue where import_module.py is. It has to know where the library is. I believe other_module.py as well as my_module.py needs to have from lib_name import import_module if they are in a library.

my_module.py

```
# Add the parent directory to the path
CURRDIR = os.path.dirname(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe()))
PARENTDIR = os.path.dirname(CURRDIR)
sys.path.append(PARENTDIR)

from lib_name import import_module

import_module.do_something()
```

ADVANCED:
The way I like to do things is to add a setup.py file which uses setuptools. This file handles distributing your project library. It is convenient if you are working on several related projects. You can use pip or the setup.py commandline arguments to create a link to the library in your site-packages python folder (The location for all of the installed python libraries).

Terminal

```
pip install -e existing/folder/that/has/setup.py
```

This adds a link to your in the easy_install.pth file to the directory containing your library. It also adds some egg-link file in site-packages. Then you don't really have to worry about pathing for that library just use from lib_name import import_module.

Comment: hmm yes when I move the file with the module it wants next to python.exe, it seems to find it

Answer (score 0):

The part of the import procedure that most programmers will need to care about is usually the first—locating the file to be imported (the “find it” part). Because you may need to tell Python where to look to find files to import, you need to know how to tap into its search path in order to extend it.

The Module Search Path Order

1. The home directory of the program
2. PYTHONPATH directories (if set)
3. Standard library directories
4. The contents of any .pth files (if present)
5. The site-packages home of third-party extensions

For editing PYTHONPATH please check [here](http://www.bdnyc.org/2012/09/17/editing-pythonpath-to-import-modules/)

Answer (score 0):

Try running your project like this:

```
$ PYTHONPATH=$(path_to_your_project) python $(path_to_your_project)/main.py
```

Answer (score 0):

While playing around with design patterns (from HF Design Patterns) I developed the following app in PyDev/Eclipse.

```
CommandPy
   |
    --  src
     |
      --    commandPy
           |--  __init__.py
           |--  command.py
           |--  garageDoor.py
           |--  garageDoorOpenCommand.py
           |--  light.py
           |--  lightOffCommand.py
           |--  lightOnCommand.py
           |--  remoteControlTest.py
           |--  simpleRemoteControl.py
```

(main app module is remoteControlTest.py).

While this works in Eclipse, I couldn't get it to work on the command line - kept getting the `ImportErrror: No module named commandPy`. After wasting hours researching what to put into `__init__.py` to try and get it to work, I saw something in another book that gave me an answer. Simply move the main app module out of the package folder like so:

```
CommandPy
   |
    --  src
     |--    remoteControlTest.py
     |
     |--    commandPy
           |--  __init__.py
           |--  .... etc
```

(do this in Ecllipse by dragging & dropping the file into the src folder and accepting the Refactor dialog).
After opening a command prompt or terminal and cd'ing into the src folder, running `python remoteControlTest.py` now works.